# Problem about ListPlot

Tags: mesh

```
pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -3}, {4, 3}, {5, 1}};
Manipulate[ListPlot[pts, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, 
  PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {min, 4}}], {min, {-4, -3, -2, -1}}]
```

You can see that sometimes the graph have some wrong points when the range of vertical coordinates are not enough. It maybe make us confused when we write Show[p1, ListPlot].

Win10, Mathematica 10.2.

I think this is a bug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug. The mesh points don't necessarily coincide with the data points. So you probably don't want to use the `Mesh` option to display the data points. It is better to use the `Epilog` option.

```
Manipulate[
  ListPlot[pts,
    Joined -> True,
    PlotRangePadding -> .1,
    PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {min, 4}},
    Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[pts]}],
  {min, {-4, -3, -2, -1}}]
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

```
Manipulate[
  ListPlot[pts, Mesh -> Full, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {min, 4}}], 
  {min, {-4, -3, -2, -1}}]
```

Maybe try `Mesh -> Full`. It might prevent one from falsely identifying wrong points and triggers you to enlarge. Hope it makes sense. But you are definitely right, it appears as a bug